# Sharing image preview is wrong

Tags: android

When I try to share an screenshot via the Samsung email app the preview of the image I am sending is wrong. It happens only with the Samsung email app.

Here is my code:

```
-------here I am taking a screenshot-----------
 String mPath = "";
        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "share" + ".jpeg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();



-------sending a screen shot via intent-----------
           Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(sorcUrl);
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           intent.setType("image/jpeg");
           intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "is wrong" means.

Comment: wrong means not the selected picture

Comment: Which one is sent instead? You should give to the point infotmation to begin with.

Comment: `Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(sorcUrl);` ??? What has `sorcUrl` to do with your former code?

Comment: sorcUrl  = String.valueOf(Uri.parse("file://" + imageFile);